# $D: \Bbb R[x]\to \Bbb R[x]$ satisfies $D(fg)=D(f)g+fD(g), D(x)=1$.Can we show that $D$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials

> $D: \Bbb R[x]\to \Bbb R[x]$ satisfies $D(fg)=D(f)g+fD(g), D(x)=1$.Can we show that $D$ is linear?

Clearly, we have $D(x^k)=kx^{k-1}$, $D(1)=0$. But these two properties can ensure that $D$ is linear?

Comment: I don't immediately see a reason why $D(x + 1) = \pi$ is forbidden (or $D(2) = x$ for that matter), but there could very well be one.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here's a thought: since every element of $\mathbb R[x]$ is a product of irreducible factors, which are linear or quadratic, the product rule tells us that $D(p(x))$ only depends on how $D$ acts on those irreducible factors, which are the linear polynomials and quadratics with negative discriminant. If we go over to $\mathbb C[x]$, it's enough to consider linear polynomials. So you could try finding such a $D$ which is not acting linearly on linear factors, that is, $D(x+a)\neq1$ for some $a$. Maybe you will find such a $D$, or an obstruction to its existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the following observation:

> **Proposition.** Let $F$ be a field, and define the operator $D : F[x] \to F[x]$ as follows:
>
> 1. For each irreducible monic polynomial $f$, assign an arbitrary value to $D(f)$.
> 2. For any non-zero polynomial $f$ with the factorization $f = c \prod_k f_k$ into (not necessarily distinct) irreducible monic $f_k$'s and $c \in F^{\times}$, set $ D(f) = f \sum_k \frac{D(f_k)}{f_k} $.
>
> Then $D$ is well-defined and solves the functional equation
>
> $$ D(fg) = D(f)g + fD(g), \qquad f, g \in F[x]. \tag{FE1} $$

In light of this, we can come up with $D$ that is not the same as the differential operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ but still satisfies $D(x) = 1$.

> **Example.** @Ennar's construction amounts to setting $D(x) = 1$ and $D(f) = 0$ for all the other irreducible monic $f$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

So, how do we prove the claim? As it will turn out, the proposition becomes almost trivial if we consider the auxiliary operator $L$ defined by

$$ L(f) = \frac{D(f)}{f}. $$

Then the functional equation $\text{(FE1)}$ is equivalent to

$$ L(cf) = L(f) \qquad\text{and}\qquad L(fg) = L(f) + L(g) \tag{FE2} $$

for any $c \in F^{\times}$ and $f, g \in F[x]\setminus\{0\}$.

Now, the uniqueness factorization property of $F[x]$ allows us to regard $M = F(x)^{\times}/F^{\times}$ as a free abelian group with the generators being irreducible monics. So, any function $L$ defined on those generators of $M$ with values in $F(x)$ uniquely extends to a group homomorphism from the multiplicative group $M$ to the additive group $F(x)$, the fact being equivalent to $\text{(FE2)}$. Then establishing the rest is straightforward.

Comment: +1, I came with my example precisely as described here, I didn't want to think about other irreducibles, so I guessed that sending them to $0$ should work. Very nice to see much more general construction.

Answer (score 7):

Define $\nu\colon\mathbb R[x] \to \mathbb N_0$ with formula $$\nu(f(x)) = \max\{ k\in\mathbb N_0 : x^k \text{ divides }f(x) \}$$
and $D\colon\mathbb R[x]\to \mathbb R[x]$ with formula $$D(f(x)) = \nu(f(x))x^{-1}f(x).$$

Note that $\nu(fg) = \nu(f) + \nu(g)$ and so $$D(fg) = \nu(fg)x^{-1}fg = \nu(f)x^{-1}fg + f\nu(g)x^{-1}g = D(f)g + f D(g)$$ and $D(x) = 1\cdot x^{-1} \cdot x = 1$. However, $D(x+1) \neq D(x) + D(1)$.